If something sounds like jazz, does that make it jazz?
Are things identifiable with a collection of properties characterizing them, or is there a difference between what a thing is vs. what it is like?

This is a question about language or music, not philosophy.

Was Beethoven a boogie-woogie swinger?

@DavidGudeman what? It may be fairly superfluous; it may need more explanation, but this is clearly philosophy.

On a side note, I think Jazz is a bad example, since “sounding like Jazz” is almost necessary and sufficient for being Jazz.

Perhaps a better philosophical example: if philosophers sound they are carving out nature at her joints, do they really carve out nature at her joints?...

The literalist folk who wield their VTCs out here need keywords. I suggest you add essentialism both Platonic and Aristotelian

@DavidGudeman: I disagree. This is part of the classic problem in philosophy, of demarcation.

in mathematics for example concepts and definitions are strict and all encompasing, in other contexts, this does not seem to apply, maybe except law, so it depends on your context definition of Jazz, and how casual you are talking.

I guess if language and music would just get it together, then you know, we wouldn't have a need for Philosophy.

"Jazz, delicious hot, disgusting cold." https://youtu.be/OmZKOFZXoJA?si=48PvPlzNOsuVAcqp vs https://youtu.be/OmZKOFZXoJA?si=aZV9x7ieMbUPkt3l


"In this sort of predicament, always ask yourself: How did we learn
the meaning of this word ("good", for instance)? From what sort of
examples? In what language-games? Then it will be easier for you to
see that the word must have a family of meanings."
-Wittgenstein, in Philosophical Investigations

It's all about context. Why a definition is needed will be important. Like often it's demarcation, to justify post hoc a feeling that some music or a musician is 'not jazz'. When we watch how humans use words we often find a misplaced sense of confidence in the certainty and precision of terms, based on a sense that 'we know it when we see it'. We can relate that to what Wittgenstein describes above, that if use is coherent and uncontentious, we tend not to investigate. It's when disagreements paradoxes or inconsistencies occur that we go deeper. Wittgenstein's view is that then we often make a mistake in thinking the meaning is 'out there' to be discovered unambiguously and objectively, when really the nature of word use is just how we convey information.
Tight definitions of many words used ordinarily in conversation, quickly run in to trouble. A famous example in philosophy is thinking about how to define a chair. We have ordinary chairs, which we can define as you say, legs, backrest. But we have weird chairs, like say a beanbag chair. And, there is using something as a chair - does that make it a chair in a sense? See eg No, Chairs Do Not Exist (blog post) for a more detailed treatment. We often use words with a 'tight centre but fuzzy edges', so might use the word stool say for a tall chair with a back, as well as without a back, there is overlap between stool and chair, and we look to context to decide if both are potentially valid labels.
In philosophy the issue is one of the nature of 'natural kinds' (SEP article), or how we organise and classify things, and what we consider that process to reveal about them. Math and science words tend to need tight definitions, because consistency and rigour are key to how those cultures work. Music is not like that, and definitions of genre are usually more for how a music shop organises records so customers can find what they like, rather than everyone agreeing how to categorise edge-cases - a bad call doesn't have very serious consequences, like say an invalid proof in math that might affect a lot of inferences from it, or a medical decision that hasn't distinguished say different types of cancer and might lead to ineffective treatment.
Like a lot of music of black origin there is a tension between how musicians involved use a genre word, and how it's used more widely. The 'know it when you hear it' approach will depend on what a person has heard, and especially if they know about edge-cased and cultural discourse on whether they are in or out of a definition, and why. A musician might start out being considered jazz, but then if they keep producing in a distinctive style it might become a sub-genre, and if other musicians join it might even become a new genre that is say 'jazz influenced' rather than considered jazz. But one track might not need such a new sub-genre or genre label, we can file it under jazz and that's good enough.

I thought it was kind of the nature of Jazz to be paradoxical and inconsistent? So then it becomes a word that basically means: "it's not one of the other genres."

@ScottRowe: Who are you asking? That's what answer you'll get.

Well I'll have to find the right person to ask then. Let's see, where is my lantern... :-)

Clearly we identify and differentiate things according to their apparent properties. How else would we do it? Macroscopic things typically have large  number of properties, some of which are more significant than others in defining the nature of the thing possessing them. For example, many mammals possess the property of having four legs. If you wish to distinguish a zebra from a horse, counting legs will not help; you rely instead on the fact that one has stripes. In everyday life, there are usually standout properties that allow you do distinguish readily between one type of thing and another.
Your question presents a false or. Yes, as I have explained, a macroscopic thing can definitely be identified by some subset of its properties. However, what a zebra is is more than its stripes.

Is a horse that was born without a leg still a horse? What are essential & what accidental? Is music going to have as much clarity as biology, aren't the processes of categorising different for different types of word? "can definitely be identified by some subset of its properties" What about the word 'nothing'?

I don't understand the relevance or point of your comment.

Right, what if it's an albino zebra?

All things arise like waves. Complex understanding is built upon simpler understanding. Precise understanding is built upon vague or fuzzy understanding. If something sounds like Jazz then probably it is Jazz. You need more data to improve your identification of it. Once more musical elements of sound becomes available you become more sure of what it is. Sometimes only a hint of Jazz or any music or thing like face or gait is enough to have confident idea of what it is. And with more data we become more confident of what it is.

That doesn't really answer the question though, it just unpacks the question. Why is this process different in music than say biology? What tools do people use to settle disagreements? What different communities come to different answers, & use different information? Can we expect everyone to always agree, or that there will always be a correct answer according to some system you can propose to 'is this jazz?'

@CriglCragl That was not what was asked. I have answered the specific question.
